# Welcome screen for Linux like Windows 10's one

Tags: linux, windows-10, packages

A feature that I appreciate a lot of Windows 10 is its welcome screen. It suggests wallpapers based on my feedback and it offers sometimes a brief cultural description of what I'm seeing, for example a narrow road on Mt. Huangshan. Does exist, for Linux, something like that?
I'm currently on Manjaro (with LightDM) but not I'm particularly interested on that distro, I'm just asking if a package (or a group of packages) exists to do what I'd want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what Linux distribution you're using, nor what desktop environment; but the short answer is, that Linux doesn't provide *exactly* what you're describing. But it does offer "Themes" that are user installable from some public repositories, which let you select a look and feel for your desktop experience from among many available. This is probably the closest thing to what you're asking about.

Specifically how to get those themes and how to install them is going to depend on what you're running, so you probably want to indicate that.

Comment: Info added. Since I use lightdm, I know I can install greeters, but it would not be a problem to switch to another DM if this particular feature existed for an another login manager.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that is proactive and adaptive as you describe. I'm not sure why this question was closed; it doesn't seem to be asking for what the close reason suggests it was asking for. But in any event, I think the answer to your question - is there something like the Windows welcome screen, that watches your interests and makes recommendations, with content descriptions, for new wallpapers or other thematic customizations? - is a **no**, for any of the desktops.  As I mentioned, you can manually browse and install different Themes, but that's about it.